# Portforward from x to 53

Tags: node.js, dnsmasq

I'm trying to run a dns server using dnsmasq which by default binds to port 53 and so requires sudo. I'm wondering if I can just run it on any unreserved port (9999) and setup a rule to forward traffic from port 53 to 9999? I'm guessing it might not work seeing as by default 53 is not open, so I would likely need something listening on port 53 that would forward the traffic to port 9999?

Answer (score 0):

Configuring dnsmasq to listen on port 9999 is done by adding line `port=9999` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and restarting the service `service dnsmasq restart`.

As per your other question about having another something listening on port 53 only to forward to port 9999, well you can certainly write a daemon to do that, and binding it to port 53 will require that you have privilege to bind to port 53 in the first place, so in your case I don't know if that's possible. Then again, if you could do that obviously you'd bind dnsmasq to port 53 in the first place...

So if your dnsmasq is listening on port 9999, you need to point your traffic to that port, wherever that traffic is coming from.